# How do I generate a textbox that only accepts numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Generate textboxes with:

```
 public void addTextBox(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            string name = "tb_" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
            tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Name = name;
            tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
            tb.Width = 20;
            x += 30;

            this.Controls.Add(tb);  
        }
    }
```

Manual formed textbox that only accepts numbers:

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        const char Delete = (char)8;
        e.Handled = !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != Delete;
    }
```

My questions: **1.** How do i set to generate texboxes that accepts only numbers?
**2.** i would like to have only two numbers (from 0 - 99  `string pattern = @"^[0-9]{2}?$";`). Or is any different way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is the textBox1_KeyPress the method to handle the validation of the Texbox input?

if so - just before adding the TextBox, add an event refference:

```
tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
```

**UPD:**

another option (this is the dirty way):

```
    tb.KeyPress += (sender, e)=>{ 
 const char Delete = (char)8;
        e.Handled = !Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != Delete;
    };
```

before the  this.Controls.Add(tb);

Comment: That's the painful way, we do it in WPF because there is no other choice.

Comment: textBox1_KeyPress works only for textBox1 (it's only exam). Generated tb are not connected to KeyPress. How can i add KeyPress to tb?

Comment: Is there any way to set `KeyPress` in `public void addTextBox` method?

Comment: @JanOlMajti yes there is. you can simply use a lmbda expression:

Comment: @Baboon well, there is actually. you may try to extend the texbox class to make it accept only two digits in winforms. the difference from WPF is that in winforms you do it in c# code, as in WPF you can configure the text box in XAML.

Comment: @JanOlMajti i've eddited the answer, added the lambda expression example.

Comment: @Igarioshka your method looks fine, but i tried this `tb.KeyPress += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text, @"^[0-9]{2}?$"))
                        {
                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
                    }
                };`

Comment: @Igarioshka and in line `if (Regex.IsMatch(tb.Text, @"^[0-9]{2}?$"))` is something wrong. Only last textbox enter is correct([0-9]{2}).

Comment: @JanOlMajti in that line try to refer to the (TextBox)sender, not the tb.

Comment: @JanOlMajti like: `if (Regex.IsMatch(((TextBox)sender).Text, @"^[0-9]{2}?$"))`

Comment: @Igarioshka It works! I like it dirty:) Thanks for replies to all

Answer (score 7):

How about using `NumericUpDown` Class? (*This could be the easiest*.) You could setup the maximum and the minimum value. You can also set it to INTEGER only.

[LINK HERE](http://www.dotnetperls.com/numericupdown)

Answer (score 5):

Use `MaskedTextBox` and set the `Mask` property to 00.

Comment: That's most definitely the way to go. Pretty much the only advantage of Winforms over WPF these days.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
   e.Handled = true;
}

private void textbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(txtStockBought.Text, "\\D+"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
    }
}


public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+"))
        e.Handled = true;
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}



public void addTextBox(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            string name = "tb_" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
            tb = new NumericTextBox();
            tb.Name = name;
            tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
            tb.Width = 20;
            x += 30;

            this.Controls.Add(tb);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool! That works for question **NO 2.** THANKS. Still wonder about question **NO 1**

Comment: Create a user control drag drop a textbox and create textbox event handler for kep press and bring it in your form....This will create a custom textbox in your form...

Comment: @StackOverflovUser try your method, but when i add `@"^[0-9]{2}?$"` i can't insert anything in textboxes.

Comment: I highly recommend that You should start to learn regular expressions first.

Comment: @StackOverflovUser Hehe, i will!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7067/discussion-between-stackoverflow-user-and-janolmajti)